# Converting Codility solution to C# (Grocery-store, Hydrogenium 2013)

Tags: c#

In order to learn and understand how Dijkstra's algorithm is used to solve the "Grocery Store" ([Hydrogenium 2013]: https://codility.com/programmers/challenges/hydrogenium2013) problem on codility, I'm trying to rewrite the #2, O(n^2) solution(https://codility.com/media/train/solution-grocery-store.pdf) in C#.

1) What language are those solutions written in?

2) What would be the C# equivalent to this bit of code?

```
G = [[]] *N
for i in xrange(M):
    G[A[i]] = G[A[i]] + [(B[i], C[i])]
    G[B[i]] = G[B[i]] + [(A[i], C[i])]
```

---

This is what I have so far

```
        int[] G = new int[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            G[A[i]] = G[A[i]];
            G[B[i]] = G[B[i]];


        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Gregory

Comment: Well first you have to tell us what language that code snippet is in, and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't know what language it's in, that's one of my questions. You can see the whole solution on the link provided. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Looking at the PDF it is Python.

Comment: @TyCobb Indeed it is Python

Comment: I've added the code I have so far. But I don't understand what is happening at the end of the lines within the FOR loop.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having other users port code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded IDLE (a python IDE...kind of) and figured it out. It appears to be adding pairs to each array element. Here's the code I came up with if anyone else happens to stumble across the same problem.

```
private struct nodePair
{
  public int node;
  public int time;
  public nodePair(int node, int time)
         {
            this.node = node;
            this.time = time;
         }

 }


 public int solution(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C, int[] D)
 {
    int M = A.Length;
    int N = D.Length;

    //build the graph
    List<nodePair>[] G = new List<nodePair>[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      G[i] = new List<nodePair>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
       G[A[i]].Add(new nodePair(B[i], C[i]));
       G[B[i]].Add(new nodePair(A[i], C[i]));
    }

    //initialize the distance table
    int[] dist = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
       dist[i] = int.MaxValue;
    }


    bool[] visited = new bool[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
       visited[i] = false;
    }

    //look for the minimum value
    int ii = 0; ;
    dist[0] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
       int s = int.MaxValue;
       //find the minimum
       for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
       {
          if ((dist[j] < s) && (visited[j] == false))
          {
             s = dist[j];
             ii = j;
          }
       }
       visited[ii] = true;
       if (s < D[ii])
       {
          return s;
       }


       List<nodePair> thisNodeLIst = G[ii];

       foreach (nodePair oneNode in thisNodeLIst)
       {
           dist[oneNode.node] = Math.Min(dist[oneNode.node], s + oneNode.time);
       }

  }//for

  return -1;

}
```

}